# How to compute transition matrix for the following Markov chain?

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Each morning a runner leaves his house and goes for a jog. He is equally likely to leave either from his front or back door. Upon leaving the house, he chooses a pair of sports shoes (or goes for a jog barefoot if there are no shoes at the door from which he left). On his return he is equally likely to enter, and leave his sports shoes, either by the front or back door.

I want to arrive at the transition matrix of the process $X_n$, where $X_n$ represents the number of shoes at the front door.

I am missing some logic and I could not arrive at the following transition matrix.

\begin{bmatrix}
    0.75       & 0.25 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0.25       & 0.5 & 0.25 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0.75
\end{bmatrix}

Can somebody help me understand this clearly? If possible, with the help of a probability tree?

Comment: There is alternative version of this solution, saying that MC should have four states and transmission probability matrix should look like $P_{00} = k/(k+1)$, $P_{01} = 1/(k+1)$, $P_{02} = 0$, $P_{03} = 0$, $P_{10} = k/(k+1)$, $P_{10} = 1/(k+1)$, etc. I wonder if you think that this is right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n = total number of shoes

The table shows the new number of shoes at the front door when returning runners:

[image]

I would say, transition probabilities:

$p_{0,0}= 3\cdot 0.25 = 0.75, \quad p_{0,1}=0.25$

$p_{i,i-1}=0.25,\quad p_{i,i}=2\cdot 0.25=0.50,\quad p_{i,i+1}=0.25, \quad i\in\langle 1, n-1 \rangle$

$p_{n,n-1}=0.25, \quad p_{n,n}= 3\cdot 0.25 = 0.75$

$\Rightarrow\,\,$ Your transition matrix.

Comment: Hi, I understood the table clearly. How did you arrive at 3x0.25 for P0,0? I am not quite getting this clear.

Comment: I think, I got the logic. Just confirm me whether my understanding is right. $P_{00}$ indicates that I have 0 shoes at both from and to doors. And, I have 3 instances of such. That is the reason why, I multiply with 3. Same for all. Is this correct?

Comment: No, if the front door is zero shoes is on the back 'n' shoes (total number of shoes = invariably 'n').

$P_{0,0}$ is the sum of the probability with which the zero shoe at the front unchanged, ie:

'front-front' (p = 0.25) + 'front-back' (p = 0.25) + 'back-back' (p = 0.25) = 0.75

(in this case only 'back-front' (p = 0.25) transmits one pair of shoes back to front $\Rightarrow p_{0,1} = 0.25$)

Comment: Ok. Got it clear now. Thank you so much.